# Unity, Build for Android: Google libraries are not found (Firebase and GoogleSignIn libraries)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-signin

I installed new Unity 2022.2.5. And I got error while build in Unity Android port (and two more similar errors for files: firebase-messaging-unity-11.6.0.pom and google-signin-support-1.0.4.pom):

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'. 
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:debugRuntimeClasspath'. 
Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:11.6.0. 
Searched in the following locations: 
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-app-unity/11.6.0/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-app-unity/11.6.0/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom 
https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal-beta-public/com/google/firebase/firebase-app-unity/11.6.0/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom 
file:////Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-app-unity/11.6.0/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom 
file:////Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/GoogleSignIn/Editor/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-app-unity/11.6.0/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom 
file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-app-unity/11.6.0/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom 
file:/C:/Unity/projects/X/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.jar 
file:/C:/Unity/projects/X/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/firebase-app-unity.jar
```

And the same thing for firebase-messaging-unity-11.6.0.pom and google-signin-support-1.0.4.pom.

But the problem is that I have these files! They are located along one of the paths from the search list. in the generated directory:
c:\Unity\projects\X\Assets\GeneratedLocalRepo\Firebase\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-app-unity\11.6.0\firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom

Action External Dependency Manager->Android Resolver->Force Resolve complete successfully.

Why am I getting an error? What could be the reason? Why Unity can't find these libraries, everything related to Google (Firebase and GoogleSignIn libraries)?

(iOS port build successfully).

I need successfully build for Android.

Comment: Are you building directly from Unity or exporting to Android studio and building from there? Are you able to access/view the file from CMD and/or the Android Studio terminal?

Comment: Building directly from Unity. The Android project is not build. He's not exist.

Comment: What do you get when you run the following from cmd.exe while Unity is still running and after you got the above error?

IF EXIST C:\Unity\projects\X\Assets\GeneratedLocalRepo\Firebase\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-app-unity\11.6.0\firebase-app-unity-11.6.0.pom (Echo EXISTS) ELSE (Echo DOES NOT EXIST)

Comment: EXIST... of course...

Comment: Could you try running through [the Debugging the Game Build, Install and Run Process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/build-debug-guide) and report if you get different results?

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly I should do. The problem is not with Firebase itself. I updated several plugins (Appodeal, Facebook SDK, Firebase), increased the version of Android Target SDK to 33 and also updated Unity from 2022.1.22 to 2022.2.5 and the assembly broke with above error.

Comment: Regardless, going through those steps and reporting the issues (if they differ) would give us a lot more information. Especially look into the steps described in[EDM4U Usage Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/troubleshooting-faq.md)

Comment: But I have no problem with EDM. External Dependency Manager->Android Resolver->Force Resolve complete successfully without errors.

Comment: What happens if you do a clean build (deleting previous build artifacts beforehand)?